# Looking at solutions while solving problems

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving, advice

I'm an undergraduate math major and in the several math textbooks I have been through I've noticed that one thing I struggle with is solving problems on my own when I have just been introduced to a new topic. Many textbooks will state the main definitions and prove the main theorems on a topic and move straight to problems, without giving any examples of applying those theorems. So, coming up with approaches myself to approach those theorems at first seems very difficult to me. In order to overcome this problem, I have tried a new approach: for the first few problems I solve on a topic, I will find a solution even before I attempt the problem (unless the problem is trivial) and glance through the solution and then reproduce it on my own (in my own understanding, not blindly write down what I read). After doing this for some problems, I find myself much better prepared to tackle more problems, because I know what kind of techniques I can use and what lines I can think along.

Is this an approached more experienced math students on this website would recommend? Does this help for more difficult mathematics? If not, what is an approach that I can use considering that I find it very difficult to solve problems before seeing several examples?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your approach, barring the trivial caveat ("make sure you do leave some of the problems for you to solve on your own"). Your approach can work like an insurance policy against not very didactically-written textbooks, or those written in hurry where the problems were an afterthought - or where the important bits that are a part of the curriculum are covered in problems only. Remember that the textbook authors are human after all, and they may excel in their field without really being good at passing their knowledge to the others.